# JS Regular Expression clarification

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to under stand the following regular expression:

```
/((id|name|field|form, )=?"?\D+)\d+/g
```

So what I can understand from the above (I think) is:
it has to start with either id, name, field and form, so lets say it is 'name' for now, after that I think '=' has to appear once or non, the same with ".  So until now the following pattern is a match: name=".

I know g at the end mean global, change all matches.

So my question is: is this `'name="hdhf1"'` which ends with a digit is a match?

Comment: Yes. And you can easily try it out yourself by running `/((id|name|field|form, )=?"?\D+)\d+/g.test('name="hdhf1"')` in the browser's console.

Comment: To clarify from the question: `it has to start with` isn't *quite* correct... it just means the first thing **you** are looking for in your pattern is `id|name|field|form` if you want to ensure that there is nothing before this you need to look for the start of the line `^`

Comment: No idea why down voting, I found this so useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Regexper**](http://www.regexper.com/#%2F((id%7Cname%7Cfield%7Cform%2C%20)%3D%3F%22%3F%5CD%2B)%5Cd%2B%2Fg) to visualise your regular expression:

[image]

If you want to test to see whether `'name="hdhf1"'` is a match, you can simply run this JavaScript code in your browser's JavaScript console:

```
/((id|name|field|form, )=?"?\D+)\d+/g.test('name="hdhf1"')
```

Spoiler alert: this will return `true` as it *is* a match!

Comment: `/((id|name|field|form, )=?"?\D+)\d+/g` is already a regex. There is no need of `new RegExp`.

Comment: Thanks, Regexper ==> so useful, lives in my bookmarks now :)

Comment: Side note: https://www.debuggex.com/ seems to be more complete (flavor choice, look arounds, unit tests...).